# Can't use 2 javascript form functions at the same time

Tags: javascript, forms, alert

So I have made 2 functions in JavaScript. one function is to check if some required input in the form is filled in. If a required is not filled in I want the page to say the input is empty.

This is the function I made in Javascript:

```
function checkform(form) {
            //Krijg all het input van de ingevulde form
            var inputs = form.getElementsByTagName('input');
            for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                if(inputs[i].hasAttribute("required")){
                    if(inputs[i].value == ""){
                        // Als er een leegveld is meld deze alert code:
                        alert("Vul alle vereisten velden in");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
```

Than I also have a function for the button to make an alert that the form was send like this:

```
function alertpopup()
        {
            alert("Uw email is verzonden! U krijgt binnen 24 uur bericht van ons.")
        }
```

Now the thing is, both work but not at the same time. If I remove the alertpopup function the checkform function does work when a required field is empty but when I do use the alertpopup function, only the pop-up pops up when I submit the form but than the checkform function isn't showing any messages when a required field is empty.

This is my form in HTML:

```
<form action="" id="form" onsubmit="return checkform(this)">

    <label for="naam"><strong>Naam*</strong></label><br>
    <input type="text" id="naam" name="naam" value="Tom" required/>
    <br><br>
    <label for="email"><strong>Email*</strong></label><br>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="tom@gmail.com" required/>
    <br><br>
    <label for="telefoonnummer"><strong>Telefoonnummer</strong></label><br>
    <input type="text" id="telefoonnummer" name="telefoonnummer" value="020-694-0232" readonly="readonly"/>
    <br><br>
    <label for="textarea"><strong>Uw vraag</strong></label><br>
    <textarea id="textarea" type="textarea" rows="10" cols="50" value="Hoe kan ik een vluchtnummer toevoegen?"required/></textarea>

    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Versturen" onclick="alertpopup()">
</form>
```

So how do I get the pop-up to sow up when the user clicks on the submit button and when all the required inputs are filled in?

Comment: Why don't you just call `alertpopup` at the end of `checkform` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want alertpopup() to call for even empty inputs then you can call it before return false; as well.

```
function checkform(form) {
            //Krijg all het input van de ingevulde form
            var inputs = form.getElementsByTagName('input');
            for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                if(inputs[i].hasAttribute("required")){
                    if(inputs[i].value == ""){
                        // Als er een leegveld is meld deze alert code:
                        alert("Vul alle vereisten velden in");

                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
alertpopup();
            return true;

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try creating another function that will wrap your whole behaviour into one:

```
function checkFormAndAlert(form) {
   const formIsValid = checkform(form);
   if (formIsValid) {
     alertpopup();
   }
   // Here you can put 'else' conditions.
}
```

I'd also suggest two improvements: it's not good to mix responsibilities (and your `checkform` function has `alert` inside. Try parametrizing popupalert function so you pass alert inside and then you can do sth like that:

```
if (formIsValid) {
   alertpopup('Correct form message');
} else {
   alertpopup('Incorrect form message');
}
```

This should get you going and be a good starting point :)

Answer (score 0):

> Than I also have a function for the button to make an alert that the form was send like this:

Just put it into the `onsubmit` method at the end if form is correct. like this:

```
function submitForm(form) {
  if(checkform(form)) {
    // send form code
    alert('form was sent')
  }
}
```

Comment: There's no popup alert showing up when I click on the button using that code

Comment: @Thijs1996 There is something with a method name. Try to use a different one. And remove `onclick` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use submit function of jQuery like

```
$( "#form" ).submit(function( event ) {
    var isvalid=checkform();
    if(!isvalid){
     alertpopup();
     event.preventDefault();
    } 
 });
```

jQuery documentation [link](https://api.jquery.com/submit/)